# DataTables: fnGetData not working after switching to server-side processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have switched from client-side to server-side processing in DataTables (version 1.10) to improve performance (adding the lines below "dom").
DataTables itself works as intended but **I am having trouble getting data from a single row or cell since then**.

```
var tableDT = $('#tblReport').dataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "data.php",
    "aoColumns": aoCols,
    // ...
```

Before I used "**fnGetData**" for this purpose as in the below example which worked fine for me but now this returns **undefined** (I don't get an error).
Is there another way to do this when using server-side processing or anything I have to change here now ?

```
$(document).on('click', '.showPrinters', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                         
    currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');             
    var itemId = $('#tblReport').dataTable().fnGetData(currentRow)[0]; // this should return the text of the first td (in my case it is hidden by default)
    // ...
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I SHARE THE FILE IN DRIVE  [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iv8Bq1iDGZVW2B82NSP-WqNG6O6brq57/view?usp=sharing][1]
server file and html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test APP</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
        </script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>     
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Click on the Edit Icon</h2>
        <table id="view_table" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
        <br>
        <div  id="console" style="height:270px; border: 1px dashed #ccc;"></div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var view_table;
        $(function () {
            initTable();
        });

        function initTable() {

            var action_init = "get_data";

            view_table = $('#view_table').DataTable({

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "server.php",
                    "type": "POST",
                    data: {
                        action: action_init
                    }

                }, responsive: true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "columns": [

                    {"data": "id"},
                    {"data": "fname"},
                    {"data": "lname"},
                    {"data": ""},
                ],
                "columnDefs": [
                    {"width": "20px", "targets": [0]},
                    {className: "center-text ", "targets": [2]},
                    {
                        "targets": [0, 1, 2],
                        "orderable": false,
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [0],
                        "visible": false,
                    },

                    {

                        "render": function (data, type, row) {

                            return '<i class="fa fa-edit edit_item" access="edit"   data-id="' + row["id"] + '" ></i>';
                        },
                        "targets": 3
                    },
                ],
                "order": [[0, "ASC"]]

            });
        }


        //HERE WE GET DATA WHEN CLICK EDIT BTN

        //edit_item LINE 77 CLASS edit_item
        $(document).on("click", ".edit_item", function () {

            var id = ($(this).data("id"));

            if ($(this).hasClass("edit_item")) {
                $("#console").text( );
                $("#console").html("You can parse the <b>getDTRow(id)</b>  AS JSON TO GET DATA <br> <br>" + JSON.stringify(getDTRow(id)));
            }
        });




        function getDTRow(id) {
            var indexes = view_table.rows().eq(0).filter(function (rowIdx) {
                // console.log(rowIdx)
                return view_table.cell(rowIdx, 0).data() == id ? true : false;
            });

            var row = view_table.rows(indexes)
                    .nodes();
            return view_table.rows(indexes).data()[0];

        }

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is fantastic and it helps a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you get Data From Datatable you can get the row alldataby the 0 index unique value
if the data matched

if your datatble var = tableDT

```
var indexes = **tableDT**.rows().eq(0).filter(function (rowIdx) {
    return **tableDT**.cell(rowIdx, 0).data() == id ? true : false;
});

var row = view_table.rows(indexes)
        .nodes();
```

//  **HERE you will get the row all data**
**tableDT.rows(indexes).data()[0];**

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! How do I get the text of the first td of the current row with this approach ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iv8Bq1iDGZVW2B82NSP-WqNG6O6brq57/view?usp=sharing